# Slowness on running java version in linux box

Tags: java, linux, performance, jvm, rhel7

I always found it difficult to troubleshoot when my java starts behaving wierd in my servers which just have the jre. Online answers suggest using commands which are basically part of jdk. What are our options when it is only jre?

**Issue:(Simplified)**
If i run the version check (applies for any java command), it takes real long to get the result.

```
java -version
```

I tried running `java -verbose version` it just hangs straight away and after a minute or so prints the whole log and version. Doesn't get stuck at a specific point!

When i run applications in this environment the process do comes up, but there is nothing happening, no logs , no life!

I tried `free -m`

```html
======total   used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:  15881   789       13694          11        1397       14807
Swap: 8191    0        8191
```

Comment: This sounds like either a very slow file system or a severe case of not enough RAM.  These problems should be diagnosed with Linux admin commands.  (The JDK tools are unlikely to help.  Your problem seems to be in JVM start up.  Probably before the JVM would start an agent that a Java diag tool could connect to.)

Comment: By RAM, I mean physical RAM.  I suspect that you are trying to run on a Linux virtual machine, and that your server is competing with other servers on the same hypervisors.  The `free` command will be reporting memory usage from the server's perspective ... not the hypervisor's perspective.  If RAM is overcommitted at the hypervisor level, performance at the server level can be terrible for any application that is (relatively) memory hungry.

Comment: If that is the problem, you will need to get your "provider" to sort it out; i.e. the people who manage things at the hypervisor level.

Comment: Thanks for the input. After a day long struggle, found the issue. In this specific case it was my symantac av which was holding up java. I killed the process and things went back to normal. But  i believe my question still stays relevant. Is there a way other than trial and error here to troubleshoot?

Comment: Erm ... well I would have thought that Linux admin tools would give you some clues.  For example, "top" should have showed that a process associated with the AV was pretty active while `java -version` was grinding away.  But this is rather off-topic for SO.  Try one of the unix / linux / ubuntu stackexchange sites.